# Directive that calls service method

Tags: angular, angular6, angular7

I created a Modal Service in Angular 7 which is used as follows [Stackblitz Example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/mk-angular-modal-service-xgteqe):

```
<button (click)="openModal()">Open Modal</button>
```

Then I defined the `openModal` method in the component's code:

```
export class AppComponent  {

  constructor(private modalService: ModalService) { }

  openModal() {
    this.modalService.open({
      component: HelloComponent
    });
  }

}
```

Is it possible to create a directive to open the modal and be used like this:

```
<button open-modal="HelloComponent">Open Modal</button>
```

Not sure about the syntax I am posting ...

Comment: Why would you want to use a directive instead of directly calling the method with a parameter? (like: <button (click)="openModal('HelloComponent')">...</button>

Comment: To not need to inject the ModalService in all components where I use it ... Make things simpler to use, no?

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve the desired behaviour by creating a custom directive:

*open-modal.directive.ts*:

```
@Directive({
  selector: '[openModal]'
})
export class OpenModalDirective {
  @Input() modalIdentifier: string;

  constructor(private modalService: ModalService) { }

  @HostListener('click', ['$event'])
  clickEvent(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    event.stopPropagation();
    this.modalService.openModal(this.modalIdentifier);
  }
}
```

dummy *open-modal.service.ts*

```
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class ModalService {

  constructor() {}

  openModal(modalIdentifier: string) {
    console.log(modalIdentifier)
  }
}
```

The directive can be used like this:

```
<button openModal [modalIdentifier]="'helloComponent'">Open Modal</button>
```

This example is [based on an article by Cory Rylan](https://coryrylan.com/blog/creating-a-custom-debounce-click-directive-in-angular) and [is available on StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/custom-open-modal-directive?file=src%2Fapp%2Fopen-modal.directive.ts).

Comment: I tried your suggestion but when using the directive I get the error: "Error: No component factory found for HelloComponent. Did you add it to @NgModule.entryComponents?". But in my App Module I have: "entryComponents: [HelloComponent]". I do not get the error when calling the service in the button. Here is my updated code: https://stackblitz.com/edit/mk-angular-modal-service-xgteqe. any idea what I am missing?

Comment: That's an unrelated issue related to dynamic components, I suggest creating another question for that.

Comment: I fixed a number of issues related to dynamic components in your stackblitz project, let me know when you created a new question.

Comment: I just did here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55695980/ngmodule-entrycomponents-and-components-created-dynamically

Answer (score -1):

You can directly call the method instead of using a directive. You can keep things simple. Directives are common layout used in more than one component.