# @NgModule.entryComponents and Components created dynamically

Tags: angular, angular6, angular7

I am opening a Modal in two different ways [Stackblitz Example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/mk-angular-modal-service-djccdy):

1. Calling a method in a component which calls the Modal Service:

   ```
   <button (click)="openModal()">Open Modal</button>

   export class AppComponent  {

     constructor(private modalService: ModalService) { }

     openModal() {
       this.modalService.open(HelloComponent);
     }

   }
   ```

   The Modal service creates the component dynamically.
2. Using a directive that then calls the ModalService:

   ```
   <button [modal]="'HelloComponent'">Open Modal</button>

   @Directive({
     selector: '[modal]'
   })

   export class ModalDirective {

     @Input('modal') identifier: string;

     constructor(private modalService: ModalService) { }

     @HostListener('click', ['$event'])
     clickEvent(event) {

       event.preventDefault();
       event.stopPropagation();
       this.modalService.open(this.identifier);

     }

   }
   ```

Option (1) works fine but option (2) returns an error:

```
Error: No component factory found for HelloComponent. Did you add it to @NgModule.entryComponents?
```

I have in my AppModule the following:

```
@NgModule({
  imports:      [ BrowserModule, FormsModule ],
  exports:      [ ModalDirective ],
  declarations: [ AppComponent, HelloComponent, ModalDirective ],
  entryComponents: [HelloComponent],
  bootstrap:    [ AppComponent ]
})
```

So I am not sure why this is not working ...

Answer (score 1):

You need to alias the reference to `HelloComponent`.

Update `app.component`

```
export class AppComponent  {

  modalComp = HelloComponent;

  constructor(private modalService: ModalService) { }

  openModal() {
    this.modalService.open(this.modalComp);
  }

}
```

and template:

```
<div style="text-align:center">
  <h1>Modal Example</h1>

  <button (click)="openModal()">Open Modal</button>

  <button [modal]="modalComp">Open Modal</button>

</div>
```

Updated stackblitz: https://stackblitz.com/edit/mk-angular-modal-service-bzn8z7?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html

Comment: Isn't there another option that defining the alias?

Comment: Not so far as i know.